# Technique to introduce normalisation/consistency to std dev comparison?

Tags: opencv, computer-vision

I am implementing a very simple segmentation algorithm for single channel images. The algorithm works like so:

For a single channel image:

1. Calculate the standard deviation, ie, measure how much the luminosity varies across the image.
2. If the stddev > 15 (aka threshold):

   - Divide the image into 4 cells/images
   - For each cell:

     - Repeat step 1 and step 2 (go recursive)

   Else:

   - Draw a rectangle on the source image to signify a segment lies in these bounds.

My problem occurs because my threshold is constant and when I go recursive `15` is not longer a good signifier of whether that image is homogeneous or not. **How can I introduce consistency/normalisation to my homogeneity check?**

Should I resize each image to the same size (100x100)? Should my threshold be formula? Say `15 / img.rows * img.cols` or `15 / MAX_HISTOGRAM_PEAK`?

**Edit** Code:

```
void split_mat(const Mat& src, Mat& split1, Mat& split2, Mat& split3, Mat& split4) {

    split1 = Mat(src, Rect(Point(0, 0), Point(src.cols / 2, src.rows / 2)));
    split1 = Mat(src, Rect(Point(src.cols/2, 0), Point(src.cols, src.rows / 2)));
    split3 = Mat(src, Rect(Point(0, src.rows/2), Point(src.cols / 2, src.rows)));
    split4 = Mat(src, Rect(Point(src.cols/2, src.rows/2), Point(src.cols, src.rows)));
}

void segment_by_homogeny(const Mat& src, double threshold) {

    Scalar mean, stddev;
    meanStdDev(src, mean, stddev);

    double dev = stddev[0]; // / (src.rows * src.cols) * 100.0;

    if (dev >= threshold) {
        Mat s1, s2, s3, s4;
        split_mat(src, s1, s2, s3, s4);

        // Go recursive and segment each sub-segment where necessary
        segment_by_homogeny(s1, threshold);
        segment_by_homogeny(s2, threshold);
        segment_by_homogeny(s3, threshold);
        segment_by_homogeny(s4, threshold);
    }
    else {
        // Store 'segment' in global vector 'images' 
        // and write std dev on it
        char d[255];
        sprintf_s(d, "Std Dev: %f", stddev[0]);
        putText(src, d, cvPoint(30, 60),
            FONT_HERSHEY_COMPLEX_SMALL, 0.7, cvScalar(200, 200, 250), 1, CV_AA);
        images.push_back(src);
    }
}


// current usage for the example image results in inifinite recursion. 
// The green and red segment never has a std dev < 25
segment_by_homogeny(img, 25);
```

[image]

I am expecting my algorithm to produce the following 5 segments:

[image]

Comment: Standard deviation doesn't depend on the number of samples. It gets less precise with fewer samples, but that cannot be your problem. Please post your code! -- Also, what are you trying to accomplish? What will you use the rectangles for?

Comment: @CrisLuengo I have posted my code. With the example image I never successfully segment the green from the red.

Comment: @CrisLuengo my problem is I get infinite recursion when segmenting (and sub-segmenting) the top left quarter of the image. As I get smaller and smaller into this image the std dev keeps rising (understandably).

Comment: Why "understandably"? For a uniform region, the std.dev should be 0. One thing to note in your code is that you only look at the red channel, so a region that differs in only the green and blue channels will look uniform.

Comment: I don't see why this wouldn't work. One thing to check is that `meanStdDev` works correctly on the cropped regions. If you see the std.dev rising it might have a bug? I can see it computing sum of squares across the full original image and normalizing by the size of the cropped region or something weird like that. Who knows? I would these it by cropping a region from the image you show here, displaying that to make sure it's uniform, and applying the `meanStdDev` function to verify it returns 0.

Comment: @CrisLuengo I would expect the stddev to grow, wouldn't you? Take my image as an example. Divide it into 4 quadrants and just look at the upper left quadrant. If I then calculate the stddev on that I would expect the stddev to rise. My code again divides that quadrant into 4, if we then look at the top left quadrant again, the stddev is lower but still not below the threshold.

Comment: Yes, but you're talking about infinite recursion. The top-left quadrant would be divided into 4, its top-left quadrant still has red and green, so it will be divided into 4, but then each of *those* quadrants (1/16ths) should be uniform. Or at least at *some* point you reach uniformity. You cannot get infinite recursion because for a single pixel the standard deviation is always 0.

Comment: Also, the algorithm never makes segments 1 and 2 in this last image. The quadrant is split into 4. You'll need some merging of neighboring regions at some point to get there.

Answer (score 0):

You can simplify your algorithm. Because you want to divide the given region into 4 subregions, you can first divide it into the 4 subregions, then calculate the average luminosity value for each, and have your threshold on the difference between these neighbor values.